# Oracle keeps showing 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis' what am I doing wrong?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_order
(
national_ID VARCHAR2 (20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES client (national_ID),
account_no VARCHAR2 (25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES account (account_no),
transaction_ID VARCHAR2 (20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES transaction (transaction_ID),
date DATE NOT NULL,
time NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
place VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
new_balance VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two issues, you can't declare foreign key constraints like that, and you can't have a column named DATE - because it's a reserved word.

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION_ORDER (
       NATIONAL_ID      VARCHAR2(20),
       CONSTRAINT ID_XFK FOREIGN KEY ( NATIONAL_ID )
              REFERENCES CLIENT ( NATIONAL_ID ),
       ACCOUNT_NO       VARCHAR2(25),
       CONSTRAINT NO_XFK FOREIGN KEY ( ACCOUNT_NO )
              REFERENCES ACCOUNT ( ACCOUNT_NO ),
       TRANSACTION_ID   VARCHAR2(20),
       CONSTRAINT TRAN_ID_XFK FOREIGN KEY ( TRANSACTION_ID )
              REFERENCES TRANSACTION ( TRANSACTION_ID ),
       DATES            DATE NOT NULL,
       TIME             NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
       PLACE            VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
       NEW_BALANCE      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Please don't change DATE to "DATE" to get around the reserved word issue - that will cause you problems in your application stack later, and esp as people try to query the data back out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong syntax, correct is:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_order
(
national VARCHAR2 (20)  REFERENCES client (national_ID),
account_no VARCHAR2 (25) REFERENCES account (account_no),
transaction_ID VARCHAR2 (20)  REFERENCES transaction (transaction_ID),
date DATE NOT NULL,
time NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
place VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
new_balance VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
);
```

Without `FOREIGN KEY`

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

This message is one of Oracle's generic syntax messages. It indicates our SQL won't compile, because the statement contains a missing keyword or comma, or a keyword out of place. In this case it's because the compiler doesn't like your inline foreign key clauses.

Inline foreign key declarations are either verbose with CONSTRAINT and FOREIGN KEY keywords as well as REFERENCES, or terse with just REFERENCES.

In fact, if you're going to use the minimalist notation why not go all in? This line ...

```
national_ID  REFERENCES client
```

...creates a foreign key to the primary key of the CLIENT table, and conforms the data type of the referencing column automatically.

So all you need is this...

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_order
(
national_ID  REFERENCES client ,
account_no   REFERENCES account ,
transaction_ID REFERENCES transaction,
transaction_date DATE NOT NULL,
time NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
place VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
new_balance VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
);
```

Note, I changed the name of `transaction_date`: plain DATE is an Oracle reserved keyword so we're not allowed to use it as an identifier.

Probably you need to make the foreign keys mandatory: a foreign key on its own won't do that. Also probably you need to add a primary key constraint.